# Linux Kernel Crypto API

Tags: c, kernel, kernel-module, cryptoapi

I''m try to make simple kernel module with using Linux Kernel Crypto API.

I've got the example from https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/crypto/api-samples.html (Code Example For Symmetric Key Cipher Operation
)

My problem is variable "*scratchpad*" (Input date) is the same value before and after launching it. 

Also bracnh is never used:

```
if (rc)
        pr_info("skcipher encrypt returned with result %d\n", rc);
```

I'm sure doing something wrong?

Comment: If you are following the example in the link, then I presume you are using `cbc-aes-aesni` as your cryptodev? What does `cat /proc/crypto` say?

Comment: Yes, i'm using cbc-aes-aesni. cat /proc/crypto said something like this: [link](https://justpaste.it/59q0k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the first part of the question:

> My problem is variable "scratchpad" (Input date) is the same value before and after launching it.

Since you are attempting to cipher in-place by passing the same scatter/gather list as a destination, this is a problem. They should not be the same.

To debug, you can:

1. Try other algorithms. I see from your `/proc/crypto` file that you have `__cbc-aes-aesni`. You may want to try that and others, to test the logic of your module.
2. Try cryptodev from userspace (`/dev/crypto`). It makes debugging much easier, by using cryptodev [tests](https://github.com/cryptodev-linux/cryptodev-linux/tree/master/tests) and examining `dmesg`. Adding `enable_stats=1` to module options also helps. When your application is stable on userspace, it's up to you to go back to the kernel.

For the second part:

> Also bracnh is never used:
>
> ```
> if (rc)
>        pr_info("skcipher encrypt returned with result %d\n", rc);
> ```

I would say this is not a problem.

Following the code sequence (referencing same kernel version v4.17 as your documentation link):

1. [`crypto_wait_req`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/include/linux/crypto.h#L507) takes an error code, in our case passed by `crypto_skcipher_encrypt()`. Unless the error is `-EBUSY` or `-EINPROGRESS`, this error code  is returned to `rc`, and zero is perfectly normal.
2. In turn, [`crypto_skcipher_encrypt`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/include/crypto/skcipher.h#L436) returns 0 if the cipher operation was successful; < 0 if an error occurred. Since you've set a key, 0 should be returned.
3. I'll reference Intel's `__cbc-aes-aesni` as the driver. Checking [`cbc_encrypt()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/arch/x86/crypto/aesni-intel_glue.c#L471), you can see zero is the return value on success, as evidenced in the return value of [`skcipher_walk_done()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/crypto/skcipher.c#L109) in successful state.

Thus it is expected behaviour on successful operation that the branch is not called.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, its helps for me! Unfortunately I can't understand why i have the same result...That's my source, could u see it? I would be very grateful! [link](https://gist.github.com/MrLebovsky/2dea79fe68dd5d94616cfd432cae469d)

Comment: @Roman, I currently don't have a 4.17 kernel ready, but there is one problem I notice which is absence of license. I think you'll get `module license 'unspecified' taints kernel.`. You can verify this after you `modprobe` by doing `dmesg | grep "Unknown symbol"`. I'll get back to you if I find anything else.

Comment: @Roman, the sample in the [link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/crypto/api-samples.html) that you originally posted is working for me. For your code, besides the above comment, it will throw an `Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address <addr>`, or something similar depending on your architecture, as you're not allocating memory using the proper APIs. Reverting to `kmalloc()` works.